# React Native how to use styles props

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props

There is my SettingsView Component:

```
<List style={styles(this.props).backgroundColorTheme}>
            <ListItem style={custom.settingsListItem} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('AppIntro')}>
              <MaterialIcons name="import-contacts" size={25} color={'#22364F'}/>
              <Text style={custom.settingsText}>
                  Покажете въвеждащата страница
              </Text>
              <Entypo name="chevron-right" size={25} style={custom.settingsDetailsArrow}/>
            </ListItem>
</List>
```

How in style attribute I can use style={styles.backgroundColorTheme} instead of style={styles(this.props).backgroundColorTheme}

There is const styles:

```
import {StyleSheet} from "react-native";

export const styles = (props) => StyleSheet.create({
    colorTheme: {
        color: props.theme.backgroundColor,
        marginTop: 60,
        marginBottom: 20,
        marginLeft: 20,
        fontWeight: '200',
        fontSize: 24,
    },
    backgroundColorTheme: {
        backgroundColor: props.theme.backgroundColor,
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of possibilities:

1. Usage of Stylesheet.flatten(Array of styles)

```
<List 
    style={StyleSheet.flatten([
          styles.backgroundColorTheme, 
          {backgroundColor: 'yourcolor'}
    ]}
>
   ...
</List>
```

2. A function that return your style

```
const getListStyle = color => ({
   backgroundColor: color,
});
...
<List 
    style={getListStyle(color)}
>
   ...
</List>
```

3. The best for me is to use `styled-components`

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ThemeColoredList = styled(List)`
   background-color: ${props => props.backgroundColor || 'yourdefaultcolorhere'}
`;

const Page = () => (
   <ThemeColoredList backgroundColor='yourcolorhere'>
      ...
   </ThemeColoredList>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `SettingsView` component just before you return from render, write `const themedStyles = styles(this.props);`. Then you can use `style={themedStyles.backgroundColorTheme}`.